# Run a C program from within a C program

Tags: c, runtime, system, sh

The question pretty much explains itself I have three different C programs and to try and compare their efficiency I tried to test their runtime by making them run several times varying their parameter (which is proportional to time taken) and write how long it takes each program to run for certain parameter (so later i can plot the results).

The following is my code

```
   # include <stdio.h> 
    # include <stdlib.h>
    # include <math.h>
    # include <time.h>  

   int main(void){

    int i;
    struct timeval bni, bmi, bfi, bnf, bmf, bff;
    FILE *in;
    char filename1[30] = "shuff.dat";
    int a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2;
    char command[100];

    in = fopen(filename1, "w");
    //for(i = 0; i<=100000; i +=100){
    for(i = 0; i<=10; i +=1){

        if (snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "./barajas_n.x %d", i) < sizeof(command)){
        a1 = gettimeofday(&bni , NULL);
        system(command);
        a2 = gettimeofday(&bnf , NULL);
        }

        if (snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "./barajas_m.x %d", i) < sizeof(command)){
        b1 = gettimeofday(&bmi , NULL);
        system(command);
        b2 = gettimeofday(&bmf , NULL);
        }

        if (snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "./barajas_fy.x %d", i) < sizeof(command)){
        c1 = gettimeofday(&bfi , NULL);
        system(command);
        c2 = gettimeofday(&bff , NULL);
        }
        fprintf(in, "%d %d %d %d \n", i, (a2-a1),(b2-b1),(c2-c1));
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

I get the following message on the terminal window:

[image: Error message]

Which means this program is running all of its steps, only not correctly executing the programs I want to time.

I've tested all three programs individually in the terminal like this

```
./barajas_*.x i
```

1. Can someone please tell me why system() is taking it's input as a directory and,
2. how to tell system() it to stop taking it as a directory and execute it?

EDIT: After a long discusion in a chat room the problem was as said by Jonathan Leffler: " a mismatch between the actual command name that existed and the command name that the program was attempting to run."

The actual question is answered by iharob's contribution, for anyone interested the snippet he provided should work if the command name matches the command name being run by the program.

Comment: If you solve the problem, don't fix the code in the question, because then it looks like you never had a problem. I undid that - if I made a mistake please tell me.

Comment: @immibis You did make a mistake! As I was trying to explain but couldnt because apparently someone with more reputation edited my edit and i wasnt able to finish my editing, Changing the syntaxis the that the arguments for system() matches its requirements does not solve the problem, but lets the program go in the for lop and show the same mistake i times for all three files.

Comment: @immibis Can you please undo your edit so I can update the question body?

Comment: I saw that someone provided an answer, and you updated the question to incorporate the answer. But if you think I was wrong, go ahead and revert my revert - I'm just another Stack Overflow user, I don't get superpowers or anything from having lots of reputation (apart from editing posts without my edits needing to be reviewed, and being able to see deleted posts).

Comment: I thought you were able to revert my edit, but here you go in case you can't.

Comment: Why is `sh` saying "`barajas_fy.x: command not found`" instead of `./barajas_fy.x`?  That suggests that you're not executing what you think you're executing.  You can also get errors if `barajas_fy.x` is a script with a shebang `#!/bin/non-existent` line (though on Mac OS X at least, the diagnosis is moderately clear: `-bash: ./x3.sh: /bin/non-existent: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.  Why aren't you showing the command lines that you're trying to execute as I suggested?  Have you tried any of the alternative command lines?

Comment: Just to be absolutely super pedantic, you can't execute C programs from C per se. You can tell the OS to execute external executables though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added the ls command, and it displays all of my barajas files, although I just noticed I was get the same error when trying to run gnuplot from the program, and it fixed when adding the full adress so i'm going to try that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And it didnt work, but now it actually complains about the directory not being found again.  /Users/.../barajas_.x no such file or directory

Comment: @CarlosSanchez: Let us continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/71134/jonathan-leffler-and-carlos-sanchez?tab=general).

Comment: After a bit of discussion in chat and seeing the actual results of running the program, we discovered that the problem was a typo — a mismatch between the actual command name that existed and the command name that the program was attempting to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system()` function takes only one argument of type `const char *`, if you need to build the command try with `snprintf()`, like this

```
char command[100];

if (snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "barajas_n.x %d", i) < sizeof(command))
{
    a1 = gettimeofday(&bni , NULL);
    system(command);
    a2 = gettimeofday(&bfi , NULL);
}
```

also, the return value of `gettimeofday()` is not useful for calculating the time difference. It's just to check errors, you can get the elapse time using this function

```
float elapsed_time(struct timeval *end, struct timeval *start)
{    
    struct timeval result;
    if (end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec > 1.0E6)
    {
        double adjust;

        adjust          = (end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec) / 1.0E6;
        start->tv_usec += 1.0E6 * adjust;
        start->tv_sec  -= adjust;
    }
    result.tv_sec  = end->tv_sec  - start->tv_sec;
    result.tv_usec = end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec;

    return result.tv_sec + result.tv_usec / 1.0E6;
}
```

and then to print the elapsed time

```
printf("Elapsed time: %f\n", elapsed_time(&bni, &bfi);
```

As the other answer mentioned you need to add a slash to execute the programs, `./programname` instead of `.programname`, but this is another solution:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

/* This function, just calculates the difference in seconds, between end and start */
float elapsed_time(struct timeval *end, struct timeval *start)
{
    struct timeval result;
    if (end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec > 1.0E6)
    {
        float adjust;

        adjust          = (end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec) / 1.0E6;
        start->tv_usec += 1.0E6 * adjust;
        start->tv_sec  -= adjust;
    }
    result.tv_sec  = end->tv_sec  - start->tv_sec;
    result.tv_usec = end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec;

    return result.tv_sec + result.tv_usec / 1.0E6;
}

/* this function will execute the command and wrap the system call
 * with 'gettimeofday()' so you can return the elapsed time while
 * the called program was running.
 *
 * It also builds the command string with the right parameter. 
 */
float run_command_and_return_time(const char *const program, int parameter)
{
    char           command[100];
    struct timeval start;
    struct timeval end;
    int            result;
    /* check that sprintf didn't need more characters */
    result = snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "%s %d", program, parameter);
    if ((result >= sizeof(command)) || (result < 0))
        return -1.0;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    system(command);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    return elapsed_time(&end, &start);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char        cwd[PATH_MAX];
    const char *filename;
    FILE       *output;

    filename = "shuff.dat";
    output   = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (output == NULL)
        return -1;
    /* get the current working directory */
    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    /* add the cwd to the PATH variable, so your barajas_*.x programs are found,
     * this way you don't need the ./bara... anymore, just bara... will do it.
     */
    setenv("PATH", cwd, 1);
    /* from here it's pretty evident what the program does */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        float a, b, c;

        a = run_command_and_return_time("barajas_n.x", i);
        b = run_command_and_return_time("barajas_m.x", i);
        c = run_command_and_return_time("barajas_fy.x", i);

        fprintf(output, "%d %f %f %f \n", i, a, b, c);
    }
    /* don't forget to close the output file */
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer please i'm new to C

Comment: @CarlosSanchez listo, que te parece?

Comment: Pues veo que lo estas explicando bien pero tengo un par de dudas, entiendo cual era el problema con system(), y entiendo que gettimeofday() no sea una buena opcion, pero por ejemplo veo que se está ejecutando el programa en fprintf(stderr, "Elapsed time: %f\n", elapsed_time(&bni, &bfi); pero no se que es stderr ni como bni y bfi me marcan el inicio y fin de un programa.

Comment: Also snprintf() didn't help with the error I got, I still have it only now the code actually enters the for loop because it gets printed multiple times.

Comment: @CarlosSanchez `gettimeofday()` solo llena la estructura con los segundos y micro segundos de la hora actual, entonces `elapsed_time()` calcula la diferencia. The problem might be that the `barajas_*` files are not in the same directory as your c program compiled executable.

Comment: @CarlosSanchez you can try to move the programs, the `barajas_*` to the same directory where you are running this program.

Comment: `stderr` is just a special system file to output errors to.

Comment: yes, thats's the first thing i though was wrong with my code, but I double checked that from the begining. that the programs are in the same directory.

Comment: How are you compiling/running the program?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so through the terminal I go ' cc program.c -o program.x' to compile it and then ./program.x to run it

Comment: try this `cc -Wall -Werror program.c -o program.x`.

Comment: I get two errors one about some implicit declaration of gettimeofday() (probably inside the if) and unused variable bnf

Comment: include `sys/time.h`. por cierto la nueva respuesta es la correcta, me habia dado cuenta pero te estaba preparando un programilla mas interesante para que trabajes sobre el, soy de venezuela y son 5 para las 11 de la noche, lo publicare y dormire.

Comment: gracias, pero no funciona. necesito que funcione el system() y aun nada.

Comment: Did you try my complete program? copy and paste? BTW, did you know of the [`time`](http://ss64.com/bash/time.html) command, you can invoke it from your shell.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why terminal keeps complaining that ./barajas_* is a directory... Yes exactly the same error

Comment: @CarlosSanchez `No such file or directory` significa, `no hay tal fichero o directorio`, it doesn't mean that your programs are directories, it means your timing program cannot find them.

Comment: so this must mean when i execute my program and call functions using system() it execute its arguments from a root directory? or perhaps just a different one? should i add the full directory adress?

Comment: the `setenv()` I added ensures that your current directory is in the `PATH` variable, which is where the shell will search for executables. I really have to sleep now, but if I wake up tomorrow and you still haven't solved it, I promise I will try to help you more.

Comment: @CarlosSanchez I'm not sure I understand what your problem is, any more than iharob does.  There are a few things you can try.  One is to run the output through something that makes control characters visible (or do a hex dump of the output).  See if there's anything untoward in the output.  You can and should print the command before you execute it, so you can see what is being sent to `system()`.  You can consider extending the command string.  For example, add `pwd;` before the command to check the directory. For another example, add `ls -l barajas*;` before the command to check the files.

Comment: when I add the     pwd; command for example it actually displays the directory the programs are located in. and still doesn't recognize the others.

Comment: You could add `echo PATH=$PATH` as another debug step.

Answer (score 1):

I note that your code currently reads:

```
if (snprintf(command, sizeof(command), ".barajas_n.x %d", i) < sizeof(command)){
```

It looks to me like you're missing a slash in that:

```
if (snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "./barajas_n.x %d", i) < sizeof(command)){
```

If that's just a typo, then one remaining problem is that [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) always returns 0:

> The `gettimeofday()` function shall return 0 and no value shall be reserved to indicate an error.

Any elapsed time is found by computation on the `struct timeval` structures, more or less as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28553176/15168) by [iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob).

#### Post-chat synopsis

I invited Carlos to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/71134/jonathan-leffler-and-carlos-sanchez?tab=general) with me.

After a bit of discussion in chat and seeing the actual results of running the program, we discovered that the problem was a typo — a mismatch between the actual command name that existed and the command name that the program was attempting to run.

Comment: Hello @JonathanLeffler, it's a typo in the question body i'll fix it right away, it still doesnt work that way.

Comment: I did notice this way after I posted my answer. The OP modified the question after I answered too.